# Grid in a border layout in extjs 4.0.0?

Tags: extjs4

how to put a grid inside the center region of border layout along with the form in extjs version 4.0.0. I am able to put the form but not the grid along with it.

source code:-

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{
            region: 'west',
            width: 200,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: true,
            html: 'West Region'
        }, {
            region: 'center'
        }, {
            region: 'east',
            width: 200,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: true,
            html: 'East Region'
        }, {
            region: 'south',
            height: 50,
            html: 'South Region'
        }]
    });

    var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'User Form',
        height: 130,
        align: 'center',
        width: 280,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
            {
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                name: 'firstName'
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                name: 'lastName'
            }
        ],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler    : function () { alert("successfully submitted");}
        }]

});
    viewport.layout.regions.center.add(form);
    // using add()
    form.show()

    });
```

Please help me put a grid below the form in the center region of the border layout in extjs 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

```
//THis is in app.js 
    launch : function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                layout : {
                    type : 'border'
                },
                defaults : {
                    split : false
                },
                items : [ {
                    region : 'north',
                    id : 'mainHeader'
                }, {
                    region : 'south',
                    height : 20,
                    id : 'mainFooter'
                }, {
                    id : 'mainContent',
                    collapsible : false,
                    region : 'center',
                    layout: 'fit'
                   }

    //----This is Controller code ---
    init: function() {
            console.debug(' controller init(). ');
             this.control({
                 'viewport > #mainContent': { //look inside a viewport component for component by id='mainContent'
                    render: this.onMainReady  //attach 'onMainReady' function to the 'render' event of the above component
                 }

    //--- this is onMainReady inside controller
               //load grid into the main content
                var main = Ext.getCmp('mainContent'); //it isnot best practice to use getCmp
                main.add({
                     xtype:'mygrid',
                     id:'whateveriwant'
                });
```

Comment: thanks for providing me with the code. but sorry to say its still not working...   :(

Comment: not working is not a good description for me to help you. This code works on my app, there must be something you are not doing right. Use FF to get some sort of understanding of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the form and the grid in the items of the center panel and set the appropriate layout.

Comment: i tried doin this but couldn't get the desirable output. infact the screen is all blank. can you provide me with some peice of code?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add component to borderlayout region. If u want to add more than one component to viewport center region then you must use a wrapper component.

Paragraph from doc: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.layout.container.Border

> The regions of a BorderLayout are fixed at render time and thereafter,
>   its child Components may not be removed or added.To add/remove
>   Components within a BorderLayout, have them wrapped by an additional
>   Container which is directly managed by the BorderLayout. If the region
>   is to be collapsible, the Container used directly by the BorderLayout
>   manager should be a Panel.

Comment: Actually i am new to extjs. so it would be really nice if you could provide me with some sample code or illustration. thanks!!

Comment: OP is not adding a new region to a border layout region (that's what's not supported), OP is adding to the panel already in the center region.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding one form 
create both the form and grid and add them at once

try this:

```
var bothforms = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 600,
    layout: 'column',//or whetever u want
    items [{
    title: 'User Form',
    columnWidth: .5,
    border: false,
    height: 130,
    align: 'center',
    width: 280,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [... ]
   },{
    title : 'User Grid',
    columnWidth: .5,
    border: false,
    height: 130,
    width: 300,
    items: [... ]
}]

});
viewport.layout.regions.center.add(bothforms);
// using add()
bothforms.show()
```